# Is there a log length limit with proc printto?

Tags: sas

I am running a huge program in SAS and am using proc printto in order to save the log elsewhere. This works for about ten hours, and then SAS switches itself back to the normal log window. It was printing to a notepad file, which only maxed out at 6718KB.

Anyone know why SAS reverts to printing in the log window? Is it just me?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would put money on you having another `proc printto` statement in there somewhere (perhaps sending listing output to a file, then clearing it).  I've certainly made logs 100x that size before.

Comment: I'm not listing anything as far as I know. The whole program is two macros, but there are a lot of different input data. I suppose I could put new printto statements in between macro calls.

Comment: Are you running the whole thing in one session, or do you use SAS/Connect to remote submit parts of your program?

Comment: One session - I just leave my work computer on. It usually stops overnight.

Comment: FYI, `listing` is the name of the output destination for 'normal SAS output' (the Output window) in version 9.2 and earlier.

Comment: If it is running a `proc printto`, it should be the last line in your log, assuming `mprint` is turned on.  I suppose it's also possible you lose connection to the drive the log file is on, if it's on a network drive (say, it happens at 10pm at night, and your servers have a nightly process that clears connections).

Comment: It happened last night at 6:17pm. No one is here around then, so it could be a network thing, though it's a bit early. It also seems to have cut out a good ten macro calls in the process >:|

Comment: Is the last line of the `printto` log a call to `proc printto`?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this would be to execute your program in batch.  In batch mode, there are no log limits, as the log is automatically printed out to a file (by default, a file that is in the same location as your `.sas` program, with the same name but `.log`).  Listing similarly will go to the same location `.lst`.

This would avoid log length limitations.  If you want your log printed to a specific place, you can use the `-altlog` startup option.